# Subtract columns in dataframe Shiny

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny

I have a dataframe. I want to make a selection of the columns I want to subtract and plot the resulting column values. When I run app I receive the following error:

**non-numeric argument to binary operator**

I understand what the error means, but I am struggling to figure out an answer. Can someone please save me from my misery?

Below is the code:

````
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

df<-data.frame('date'=c('2020-01-01','2020-01-02','2020-01-03'),
               'a'=c(1,3,8),'b'=c(2,4,9),'c'=c(0,1,7))

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
      column(width=4,pickerInput('input1','Select 1',names(df[,-1]))),
      column(width=4,pickerInput('input2','Select 2',names(df[,-1]))),
      plotOutput('plot')

))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    dt<-reactive({df%>%mutate(diff=input$input1-input$input2)})

    output$plot<-renderPlot({ggplot(dt(),aes(date,diff))+geom_point()})

}

shinyApp(ui, server)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `!!` with `as.name` :

```
mutate( diff = !!as.name(input$input1) - !!as.name(input$input2) )
```